# Conditional Sum (based on current week)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel 2010 Workbook.  Within this there are two columns.

The first column represents numerical week 1 (1-52 rows), the second contains a numeric value (never blank)

I would like a formula which basically sums all the rows (2nd column) up until the current week.  So today it would sum the rows 1 through 11, next week it would sum 1 through 12

Tried a SUMIF but could not get it working (always zero)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A52,"<="&WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2),B1:B52)
```

Where your week numbers run from `A1:A52` and your values run from `B1:B52`.

You can also define which day the week begins on within the `WEEKNUM()` function by changing the second parameter. It is currently set to `2` which is based on the week beginning on Monday.